# How to get all values from a table in spring boot with where condition?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I am learning `Spring Boot` and basically want to make a query like this **that returns all rows whose age is 5.**

`SELECT * FROM pets WHERE age = 5;`

With Spring Boot, getting all pets or a pet with a unique id is easy using the `JPA` and `Hibernate` and I can simply do this.

PetsController.java

```
//for all pets
@GetMapping
    public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
        return petService.getAllPets();
    }

//for getting one pet with unique id
@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Pet> getPetById(@PathVariable("id") int petId) {
        ResponseEntity<Pet> matchingPet = new ResponseEntity<Pet>(petService.getPetById(petId), HttpStatus.OK);
        return matchingPet;
    }
```

PetService.java

```
public interface PetService {
    List<Pet> getAllPets();
    Pet getPetById(int petId);
}
```

PetServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PetServiceImpl implements PetService {

    private PetRepository petrepository;

    public PetServiceImpl(PetRepository petrepository) {
        this.petrepository = petrepository;
    }


    @Override
    public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
        return petrepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Pet getPetById(int petId) {
        Optional<Pet> pet = petrepository.findById(petId);
        if (pet.isPresent()) {
            return pet.get();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

PetRepository.java

```
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> {
}
```

Since getting list of pets and getting pets by id was easy enough by using the `JpaRepository`, I was wondering if there are any methods available that does something similar that returns all pets whose age is 5. Or would I need to make a custom query for this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just going to do a search by age, you can use [Query creation from method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) method.

```java
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> {
    List<Pet> findAllByAge(Integer age);
}
```

`OR`

Alternatively, you can also use the [`@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) to apply your query.

```java
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> {
    @Query("select p from Pet p where p.age = ?1")
    List<Pet> findAllByAge(Integer age);
}
```

**Note:** If you have too many criteria or if you want to search according to certain conditions, you should use [`Specification`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).

Comment: Very strange. How does it know to do that in your first solution? I am guessing the "age" parameter is matched with the table's column name? Also why did you use (Integer age) instead of (int age) in the parameter?

Comment: Yes, [`Spring Data JPA`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) does it from method name. You can use `Integer` or `int`, it depends on how you work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> {
    List<Pet> findAllByAge(Integer age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your repository you can create a method like:

```
public List<Pet> findByAge(Integer age);
```